# required attribute is not working on select2 plugin initilized using remote data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 plugin with remote data in one of my project and required attribute is not working on it, however required works fine without remote data.

required Works fine on below code.

```
<select name="data[trip_advance_card_id][]" class="select2 payment_cards" style="width: 100%;" required>
    <option value="">SELECT PAYMENT CARD</option>
    <?php foreach($payment_cards as $payment_card) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $payment_card['payment_cardid']; ?>">
        <?php echo $payment_card['payment_card_no']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<script>
   $('.select2').select2();
</script>
```

required not working on below code

```
<input type="hidden" class="payment_cards" name="data[trip_allowance_card_id][]" style="width: 100%;" value="" required>
<script>
     $(".payment_cards").select2({
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                callback({"id":"","text":"SELECT PAYMENT CARD"});
            },
            ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo site_url('accounts/payment_cards/json_search'); ?>",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                quietMillis: 50,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term,
                        vehicle_id: $(this).closest('.single_trip_allowance').find('select.vehicle_no').val()
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.text,
                                id: item.id
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved the issue by myself.

changed type="hidden" to type="text" in input field

```
<input type="hidden" class="payment_cards" name="data[trip_allowance_card_id][]" style="width: 100%;" value="" required>
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="payment_cards" name="data[trip_allowance_card_id][]" style="width: 100%;" value="" required>
```